# GitLab centos8 nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have installed gitlab on a subdomain `gitlab.foo.com` it is working, now this is on a raw VPS, at first wast thinking on getting a webpage but now i want a page for that I want to use the main domain `foo.com`, I have configure the domain to do so and is working with html files, just recently installed php and also is working.

The problem I have now is that I want to install an SSL for this domain `foo.com` so I have installed the `CertBot` but when running `cerbot --nginx -d foo.com -d www.foo.com` it throws an error, `The nginx plugin is not working`, i have searched for this kind of error but no luck

so, `gitlab.foo.com` is working just fine with httpS!
`foo.com` is not working with httpS, also I want to use Laravel for my main website.

So, `certbot --nginx` is not working since `--nginx` is part of gitLab, also `postgres` is not global is also part of gitlab.
What I don't want is to use gitlab with a port on the URL `gitlab.foo.com:81`

So, I need some sort of LAMP + gitlab, anyone knows how to do it and share it? or maybe you know a tutorial on how is done... I have spend 3 days searching and testing.

Comment: How about setting up nginx so that certbot works well with it? Which version is installed, and can certbot find its path? Otherwise, try the `standalone` or `webroot` plugins to setup the certbot certificate? https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html?path#getting-certificates-and-choosing-plugins

Comment: @Mehdi, thank you, yes CertBot is installed not part of Gitlab software, gitLab has its own way to generate their certificate, one thing is for sure, is not using Certbot so I had to install it, So, first I was on CentOS8 using the default libraries of GitLab and tapping in to them for other uses like setting up my html website, didn't worked so well, I had to re-install everything including the main OS which now is Debian 10, apache, php, mysql, fw, waf..etc like any other host, plus GitLab, it turnout to work much better in apache than nginx, still testing so that I post and answer, if...